# OData.Simple.Client Linking "Attempt to access the method failed."

Tags: c#, api, rest, exception, odata

I am trying to link my entries using OData.Simple.Client

```
    public async Task AddGenresAsnyc(int UserID, List<Genre> Genres)
    {
        await client.For<User>.Key(UserID).LinkEntryAsync(x => x.Genres, Genres);
    }
```

This is the method I am using in order to do it. However when I run it it throws the exception

> "Attempt to access the method failed."

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is there any related action defined in your controller?

Comment: No, but in tutorials there was no mentioning of it.

Comment: I create a [sample project](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/master/SelfHostSample/SimpleODataClientApp). It works fine at my side.

Comment: Well that doesn't help me, isn't it?

Comment: I'm running into the same exception when calling UnlinkEntryAsync. Anyone find a solution/work-around?

Comment: I have a work-around. However it is very chessy.  I send the id's like: string ids = "2|3|4|10|32" then I split the string by '|' and do the work using EF. I use Odata custom functions to send data to the backhand. Hope this brief explanation helps.